# Formsubmit.co form submission using AJAX doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I wanted to create a submit form for my website without writing the php myself so I decided to use formsubmit.co. Though I want to prevent the submission from redirecting out of the web page and instead show success message that appears after. Here is the code I have tried below:

HTML form:

```
<form id="contactForm"  action="https://formsubmit.co/e2eabf6821c9d873df8a5a3dbe11c6b2" method="POST">
                                <div class="fields">
                                        <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display: none;">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
                    
                                        <div class="field half">
                                            <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="name" id="fullName">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field half">
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field half">
                                            <label for="company">Company</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field half">
                                            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                                            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                        <button class="button primary submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                                    
                                </form>

                                <p id="form_success">Thank you for contacting me. I will be in touch as soon as I can.</p>
```

Jquery AJAX configuration:

```
 // Get a reference to the form and the success message element
         const form = document.getElementById('contactForm');
         const formSuccessMessage = document.getElementById('form_success');
 
         // event listener to the form for the submit event
         form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
             // Prevent the default form submission behavior
             event.preventDefault();
 
             // Get form field values
             const name = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
             const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
             const company = document.getElementById('company').value;
             const subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
             const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
 
             // Send form data using AJAX
             $.ajax({
                 method: 'POST',
                 url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/myemail@gmail.com',  //ownformsubmit email
                 dataType: 'json',
                 accepts: 'application/json',
                 data: {
                     name: name,
                     email: email,
                     company: company,
                     subject: subject,
                     message: message
                 },
                 success: (data) => {
                     // Display the success message
                     formSuccessMessage.style.display = 'block';
                 },
                 error: (err) => {
                     // Handle errors
                     console.log(err);
                 }
             });
         });
```

When I try this, it doesn't work and comes with an 404 error. Is there anyway I can make this work?

Here is the documentation I got my reference from:

https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation